# What was the first gene(s) found to code for ncRNA

Tags: transcription

I could not find a source that states what the first gene found to code for ncRNA was. Someone told me, however, it was a gene that coded for either rRNA or tRNA. To this point in time I have had no other confirmation that this is true.

Answer (score 2):

The first eukaryotic genes cloned were the 18S and 28S rRNA genes from the frog *X. laevis* as described here: http://www.genome.gov/25520303

And yes, they are definitely ncRNA genes.

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. I asked what the first gene or genes found to code for ncRNA were. Not the first genes cloned.

Comment: I don't think you read my answer; the first eukaryotic genes cloned actually __were__ ncRNA genes.